# FlexBE OSX Sierra

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

GOOGLE drops ChromeAPP support  next year and I'm searching for new FlexBE UI solution.

Is there any way to use FlexBE UI without chrome similar to SimpleDockerUI ?

This UI was ported to a standalone APP. https://github.com/felixgborrego/simple-docker-ui

Story: a lot of students have own Macs with OSX Sierra but they are unable to install ROS (not supported or working).

Feedback welcome :-)

Cheers

Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259853/flexbe--osx-sierra/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2017-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Christian,

thank you for your interest in FlexBE! We are aware of the Chrome App EOL, [see statement here](https://github.com/pschillinger/flexbe_chrome_app/issues/11). There is already a standalone version of the App:

https://github.com/FlexBE/flexbe_app#flexbe-app

It is currently in beta, but has already all the features and as far as feedback reaches me, it mostly works at least as good as the old Chrome App. It has mostly been tested on Ubuntu, but [let me know](https://github.com/FlexBE/flexbe_app/issues) if you should encounter any problems on OS X.

**EDIT:** To run the existing Chrome App without Chrome, you can download [nw.js](https://nwjs.io/) and clone [flexbe_chrome_app](https://github.com/pschillinger/flexbe_chrome_app). Assuming you downloaded and extracted both into the same folder, run something like the following command to start the App:

```
nwjs-v0.xx-.../nw flexbe_chrome_app/FlexBE
```

There should be no difference compared to running it with Chrome.

---

Originally posted by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) with karma: 321 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-04-21**:
Hi Philipp,

I have no ROS environment at my OSX Sierra, it is not supported and not working currently :-(

How can I use FlexBE UI without ROS environment ? This was an amazing feature of the chrome-app.

Thanks for suggestions or hints

Cheers

Christian

**Comment by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) on 2017-04-23**:
I see. Yes, the new app uses ROS directly on the system, there is no websocket like rosbridge used anymore. I updated my answer with a way to run the old Chrome App without Chrome. I might add rosbridge connection again to the new App, but there are no concrete plans for it right now.

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-04-24**:
Thanks for your friendly answers !!!